# Are there hidden dangers with using delayed queues?

Tags: queue, delay, message-queue

Most of the common use cases that I've found with delayed messages have typically used short lived delays of seconds, minutes, or hours for things such as rate limiting and de-duping.

The question is what special considerations should there be for events that delay for much longer? Say for days, or even weeks. I'm more interested in actual problems someone has encountered, or heard of, but theoretical concerns are welcome beyond the obvious things such as persistent messages. Would the opportunity for deserialization errors be more pronounced? Are there operational concerns to be weighed?

Comment: Many queues are in-memory and prone to data loss in a crash. You'd have to keep your job processing logic backwards-compatible for as long as the maximum amount of time a job might sit in queue. Plenty of things, but IMO this is way too broad for a SO question.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this. After adding delayed messages that last for days we encountered an issue with how the default AMQ scheduler manages journal files. It uses the same journal for immediate and scheduled messages. Which in turn meant they couldn't be purged/truncated until all are delivered. This resulted in disk space being eaten up.